# Resolution change when lid closed

Tags: 18.04, power-management, thinkpad

Recently I made a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 on my Thinkpad X1. I noticed that after I wake the system up from suspend, the windows are tiny. The system seems to change screen resolution when I open the lid. Indeed, the lock screen clocked is huge for a split second after opening the lid, then the screen resolution is changed to my normal 2560x1440.

When I suspend from the command line and wake up with the power button, the screen does not change resolution.

When I suspend from the command line, then close the lid, opening it resizes the windows.

The only suspicious line in logs was this one from `/var/log/kern.log`.

`Reducing the compressed framebuffer size. This may lead to less power savings than a non-reduced-size. Try to increase stolen memory size if available in BIOS.`

Might this be a hint to change something? If so, what?

Previously I run Ubuntu 16.04 on the Thinkpad and did not have any problems with the display.

Ubuntu version: 18.04.2 LTS

Hardware: Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 4th Gen

Comment: How do you suspend from the command line?  Are you using S3 sleep or S2 sleep?  Can you explain more precisely how the resolution changes when you resume and what your normal resolution is?  Finally, posting the output of dmesg showing the suspend/resume cycle would help.